# Find the angle of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I'v tried to solve this problem but did not get the right result.

Triangel PQR is PQ = 5,0 cm, QR = 6,3 cm and RP = 7,4 cm. Calculate angle P.

I tried to solve it by using by using the following formula $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2abcosP$. The result I get is 41 degrees but the correct result seems to be 57 degrees.

I used the following steps.

$cosP = (a^2+b^2-c^2)/(2 \cdot a \cdot b )$

Thanks!

Comment: Is your calculator in radian mode?

Comment: Did you use c = 6.3?

Comment: How do I know that c = 6.3?

Comment: By the way, why do you denote $\;\cos C\;$ instead of $\;\cos P\;$ or even $\;\cos\angle QPR\;$ ? Perhaps this misled you...?

Comment: I misspelled sorry!

Comment: @S4M1R, it still makes no much sense in your question, as what is $\;a,b,c\;$ ? Do you mean $\;a=PQ\;$ , or perhaps $\;a=PR\;$ ...? You must be way more careful with your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the solution I get is $\;57.215^\circ\;$ . You have the right formula but maybe you messed between the sides. It should be

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{5^2+7.4^2-6.3^2}{74}$$